# Правка содержимого textarea посредством JavaScript

Tags: textarea, javascript

День добрый. Имею поле ввода textarea и потребности править его содержимое посредством js (на серверной части тяжко благодаря вычурной фантазии авторов ViArt'а). Обрабатываю как

```
 <textarea onLoad = "this.innerHTML = 'pupkin'">
```

, но js определяет значение как NaN. Как посоветуете?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined # Хм...
http://ngtt.ru/mebel38/user_profile.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<textarea>pupkin</textarea>` либо `<textarea id="ta"></textarea><script>document.getElementById('ta').value='pupkin';</script>`

Comment: спасибо огромное :)